# Iterate through array to find values that equal a specified sum

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a function that will yield the following output:

```
// Required sum

console.log([3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3, 6, 0].elementsTheSumTo(6)) // [ [3, 3], [4, 2], [6, 0] ]

console.log([7, 0, 5, 8, 0, 0, 7, 7].elementsThatSumTo(7)) // [ [7, 0], [0, 7], [0, 7], [0, 7] ]
```

I've tried with,

```
Array.prototype.elementsThatSumTo = n => {
    let result = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < this.length; j++) {
            if (j !== i && (this[i] + this[j] === n) {
                result.push([ this[i], this[j] ]);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

But that's yielding unexpected behavior. I was also thinking of using `reduce`, but that didn't seem to work either. Not sure how to figure this one out.

Comment: For `[7, 0, 5, 8, 0, 0, 7, 7]` there are 9 ways to sum exactly two numbers to `7`, not four. Why aren’t three `[7]`s in the result? Why not `[7, 0, 0]`?

Comment: Neither of the "solutions" makes sense... The second has duplicated entries which would also be possible for the first input. Also the first has the wrong solution `[3, 2]` and is missing `[3, 2, 1] `

Comment: Apologies, typo on my end. The elements must equal the provided sum and there can only be two elements, no more (so it can't be 7, 0 0)

Comment: In first output, why is `[4, 2]` only once? There are `2` twice

Comment: _"Apoligies, ..."_ - Then fix the question, and also add the new requirements (_"only two elements"_).

Comment: Does it need to be an array prototype? that doesn't really makes sense to have it as an array prototype, since it shouldn't alter the original array at all and doesn't really sound as an utility of the array itself.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the elements from the array when matches are found, which can be done with `splice`. You also need to use a full-fledged `function` to access the `this`, the array instance:

```js
Array.prototype.elementsThatSumTo = function(n) {
    const arr = this.slice(); // avoid mutating the input array
    const result = [];
    while (arr.length) {
        const num1 = arr.shift();
        const num2Index = arr.findIndex(num => num1 + num === n);
        if (num2Index === -1) {
            continue;
        }
        result.push([num1, arr[num2Index]]);
        arr.splice(num2Index, 1);
    }
    return result;
}

console.log([3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3, 6, 0].elementsThatSumTo(6)) // [ [3, 2], [4, 2], [6, 0] ]

console.log([7, 0, 5, 8, 0, 0, 7, 7].elementsThatSumTo(7)) // [ [7, 0], [0, 7], [0, 7], [0, 7] ]
```

Keep in mind that mutating built-in prototypes is *very* bad practice. If possible, consider using a standalone function instead:

```js
const elementsThatSumTo = (arrInit, n) => {
    const arr = arrInit.slice(); // avoid mutating the input array
    const result = [];
    while (arr.length) {
        const num1 = arr.shift();
        const num2Index = arr.findIndex(num => num1 + num === n);
        if (num2Index === -1) {
            continue;
        }
        result.push([num1, arr[num2Index]]);
        arr.splice(num2Index, 1);
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(elementsThatSumTo([3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3, 6, 0], 6)) // [ [3, 2], [4, 2], [6, 0] ]

console.log(elementsThatSumTo([7, 0, 5, 8, 0, 0, 7, 7], 7)) // [ [7, 0], [0, 7], [0, 7], [0, 7] ]
```

Comment: `shift` will mutate array. Also, you can just use `find` and check for `null` for invalid case

Comment: That's why I said to `slice` first to avoid mutating. Issue with `find` is that it gets more complicated to remove the found element

Comment: I added comment before your update. I'll remove it. But just a point, `slice` + `findIndex` + `splice` looks too complicated to me and involves too much operation. Removing elements would be required in my POV but even without it, it looks complicated. I would still prefer using for as that is simpler and more efficient in this case. My POV though

Comment: The only other option would be to keep track of the index of every element that's been removed, which would look a bit worse IMO

Answer (score 1):

That's because for every number you are also seeing for the combinations that are already covered. Just change (j=0) to (j=(i+1)) in your code it will work fine and you can also ignore the check(j==i) then.

```js
Array.prototype.elementsThatSumTo = function(n) {
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
      for (let j = (i+1); j < this.length; j++) {
          if (this[i] + this[j] === n) {
              result.push([ this[i], this[j] ]);
          }
      }
  }

  return result;
}

console.log([3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3, 6, 0].elementsThatSumTo(6)) // [ [3, 3], [4, 2], [6, 0] ]

console.log([7, 0, 5, 8, 0, 0, 7, 7].elementsThatSumTo(7)) // [ [7, 0], [0, 7], [0, 7], [0, 7] ]
```

Comment: This does not produce the desired output.

Comment: Updated it to use an anonymous function instead of an arrow function as `this` was pointing to incorrect scope

Comment: It doesn't splice the elements out of the array. CertainPerformance's answer does. Also, `[6,0]` is not in the output in the first array

Comment: @MikeK I just wanted to let you know that from the algo you've used you might end up counting the pairs which are already considered.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a `Map` and store the visited elements and cound the occurence.

```js
Array.prototype.elementsThatSumTo = function (sum) {
    var map = new Map,
        i, l, v
        result = [];
    for (i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) {
        v = this[i];
        if (map.get(v)) {
            map.set(v, map.get(v) - 1);
            result.push([sum - v, v]);
            continue
        }        
        map.set(sum - v, (map.get(sum - v) || 0) + 1);
    }
    return result;
}

console.log([3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3, 6, 0].elementsThatSumTo(6)) // [ [3, 2], [4, 2], [6, 0] ]
console.log([7, 0, 5, 8, 0, 0, 7, 7].elementsThatSumTo(7)) // [ [7, 0], [0, 7], [0, 7], [0, 7] ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
Array.prototype.elementsThatSumTo = function(n) {

  var result = [],
    len = this.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len - 1; i++)
    for (var j = i + 1; j < len; j++)
      if (this[i] + this[j] == n)
        result.push([this[i], this[j]]);

  return result;
}


console.log([3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3, 6, 0].elementsThatSumTo(6))
```